# How might I make a shortcut for switching my macbook into airplay screensharing mode with my apple tv?

Tags: appletv, airplay, menu-bar, launchpad, shortcut

Now that Apple TV shares synchronized audio&video from my Macbook without any limitations or constraints (seamlessly), it seems pretty common sense that there might be a (Launcher or topbar) shortcut out there that could toggle my airplay configurations between on and off. Is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the Available AirPlay Display icon that's on the menubar allowing you to opt to AirPlay whatever is on your screen to an Apple TV? It looks like a rectangle with an arrow at the bottom that is pointing upward. If you don't see it on the menubar, go into Display Preferences in System Preferences and toggle the option on.

Comment: System Preferences > Display > "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available." Got it. Thank you!